# Animate left side menu sliding in

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations, styled-components

I have seen SO solutions for other side bar menus but haven't found one for this specific use-case so far.

I have a vertical side bar menu. Ideally the vertical side bar menu could be imported from a package and reused in another app, so it should have animation built-in, instead of relying on a consuming app to animate.

Clicking a button on the side bar opens the menu and content to the right of the menu is pushed further right. This is working so far.

[image]

[image]

I am trying to add animation, so the menu slides in from left to right as it opens. I tried combinations of width, left, keyframe animation to animate Menu but got unexpected results.

Any idea how to accomplish this? Sample code below.

Page component

```
import SideBar from "../../components/sideBar/component";

const Page = () => {
    const config = [
        { item: "b 1", content: <div>button 1</div>},
        { item: "b 2", content: <div>button 2</div>}
    ];

    return (
        <PageContainer>
            <SideBarContainer>
                <SideBar config={config} />
            </SideBarContainer>
            <ContentContainer>
                page content
            </ContentContainer>
        </PageContainer>
    )
};

export default Page;

const PageContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
`;

const SideBarContainer = styled.div`
    height: 100%;
`;

const ContentContainer = styled.div`
    height: 100%;
`;
```

SideBar component

```
import { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Menu } from "../../components/menu/component";

const SideBar = ({ config }) => {
    const [contentIndex, setContentIndex] = useState();

    const onClick = (index) => {
        if (index === contentIndex) {
            setContentIndex();
        } else {
            setContentIndex(index);
        }
    }

    const buttons = config.map((c, index) => {
        return (
            <div key={c.item}>
                <button onClick={() => onClick(index)}>
                    {c.item}
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    })

    return (
        <SideBarContainer open={contentIndex !== undefined}>
            <Bar>
                {buttons}
            </Bar>
            <Menu open={contentIndex !== undefined}>
                {contentIndex !== undefined && config[contentIndex].content}
            </Menu>
        </SideBarContainer>
    );
}

export default SideBar;


const SideBarContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
`;

const Bar = styled.div`
    width: 64px;
    min-width: 64px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 1;
`;
```

Menu component

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const Menu = ({ children, open }) => {
    return (
        <MenuContainer open={open}>
            {children}
        </MenuContainer>
    );
};


// width: ${({ open }) => open ? '300px' : '0px'};
// left: ${({ open }) => open ? '0px' : '-300px'};

const MenuContainer = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    width: ${({ open }) => open ? '300px' : '0px'};
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
`;


// animation-name: ${({ open }) => open ? 'slidein' : 'slideout'};
// animation-duration: 2s;

// @keyframes slidein {
//     left: 0px;
// }

// @keyframes slidein {
//     width: 300px;
// }
```